# Trying to Make a Field of View (FOV)

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

I'm using Javascript to study and make a RayCasting game like Doom, the first challenge i'm coming through is about rotating things.

```
            cCenter= [this.x+this.width,this.y];
            //this.desenho represents my canvas context
            this.desenho.beginPath();
            this.desenho.strokeStyle = "blue";
            
            initX = cCenter[0] + this.width  * Math.cos(this.radians());
            initY = cCenter[1] + this.height * Math.sin(this.radians());
            this.desenho.moveTo(initX-this.width,initY); //initX-this.width Cause i have my origin point in the top corner of the cube.
           

            //this.radians() returns the current angle my cube is in radians
            initX = initX + 100* Math.cos(this.radians());
            initY = initY + 100* Math.sin(this.radians());
            
            this.desenho.lineTo(initX,initY);
            this.desenho.stroke();
```

I already try a bunch of coordinates formulas, i just want two lines following the edges of a cube to make a field of view.

OBS: I cant just get the cube coordinates because when i use "this.desenho.rotate()" it does not change the coordinates of the points

Answer (score 1):

Solved, i just give up and make the rects drawning paths and saving the coordinates of the respectives points:

```
rotationMath(point, centro,vel) {
    let x = centro.x + (point.x - centro.x) * Math.cos(this.radians(vel)) - (point.y - centro.y) * Math.sin(this.radians(vel));
    let y = centro.y + (point.x - centro.x) * Math.sin(this.radians(vel)) + (point.y - centro.y) * Math.cos(this.radians(vel));
    return { x, y };
}
```